# Image being clipped when copied to HTML canvas using drawImage

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am writing a small snippet that allows a user to drag an image into a div container (dropzone) and then creates a canvas in that div and paints the image into the div. But, this does now work and I simply am unable to figure it out. The problem is that the image is being clipped for some reason. I can confirm that the image is loaded correctly cause if instead of a canvas I append an image object, it works! The entire image is displayed. I have also tried explicitly entering the width and height into the `drawImage` parameters with no success.

```
function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  if(files)
    readFile(files[0]);
}

function applyDataUrlToCanvas(dataUrl) {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = dataUrl;

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  };
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function readFile(file) {

  var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');

  for (var i = dropzone.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    dropzone.removeChild(dropzone.childNodes[i]);
  }

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.id = 'mainCanvas';
  canvas.style.display = "block";
  canvas.style.margin = "auto";
  dropzone.appendChild(canvas);

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    applyDataUrlToCanvas(this.result);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You are not specifying the size of the `Canvas` element anywhere (at least not in the code shown here).

If size for canvas isn't specified it will default to 300 x 150 pixels.

You can update the canvas' size at anytime so here it might be a good idea to do the following if size of image is unknown:

```
img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```

Not specifying size when using `drawImage` will use the original size of the image so here it's not necessary as here we 'll know the canvas will be as big as the image.

Comment: Omg!!! I assumed that style.width and style.height are the same thing as .width and .height! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @RajivNair no, you must not use CSS styles for this as CSS only scales the content (just as an image). Remember to up-vote/accept answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Just had the same issue. Did not realize that you had to explicitly set the size of the canvas. This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I have canvas width and heihgt set to 100% in css setting so:

```
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
```

in page load event do the trick