# SVG in DOM is not drawn on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw an SVG which is appended in my DOM on a dynamically created HTML 5 canvas

But cant able to draw it. Find the sample in the below link
http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/Sync_wnoo553d

But the SVG is not draw on the canvas. If draw any SVG/image from a URL, it is drawn fine. But not working only when drawn a DOM element dynamically.

My code snippet is

```
var img = new Image();         // draw svg on canvas             
 img.onload = function () {
    exprtCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
 img.src = svg;
```

Where svg is the variable holding the SVG element in DOM.

Guide me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you constructing the DOM element.

Comment: I am creating a SVG element dynamically with required attributes and appending it to the body of the document . Kindly have a look at the attached sample link. So that you can be clear.

Comment: Code should be in the question and not elsewhere. Most links are blocked form my current location for instance.

Comment: I run you code from jsplayground in chrome & it seems to work?

Comment: "*svg is the variable holding the SVG element in DOM*" like `svg = document.querySelector('svg')` ? That won't work. Ultimately, that will make your `img.src` set to `"[object SVGSVGElement]"` which obvioulsy won't do any good. You'll have to serialize your DOM element to a string an then make it a valid dataURI (or blobURI depending on the method you choose) before using it as an url. This [Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230293/how-to-convert-svg-to-png-using-html5-canvas-javascript-jquery-and-save-on-serve/33227005) shows you how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert svg to png using html5 canvas/javascript/jquery and save on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230293/how-to-convert-svg-to-png-using-html5-canvas-javascript-jquery-and-save-on-serve)