# SVG to image conversion trouble

Tags: javascript, svg, chartist.js

I'm trying to convert the following SVG string to image with JS:

```
<svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="100%" class="ct-chart-line" id="test-chart" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="ct-grids"><line y1="165" y2="165" x1="50" x2="406.984375" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="115" y2="115" x1="50" x2="406.984375" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="65" y2="65" x1="50" x2="406.984375" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line><line y1="15" y2="15" x1="50" x2="406.984375" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line></g><g><g series-name="performance" class="ct-series ct-series-a"><path d="M50,165C53.57,165,403.415,155,406.984,155" class="ct-line"></path></g><g series-name="bemchmark" class="ct-series ct-series-b"><path d="M50,165C53.57,165,403.415,45,406.984,45" class="ct-line"></path></g></g><g class="ct-labels"><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="40" y="170" width="356.984375" height="20"><span class="lineChartLabel ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 357px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Jan</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="396.984375" y="170" width="30" height="20"><span class="lineChartLabel ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 30px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">Feb</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="115" x="10" height="50" width="30"><span class="lineChartLabel ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">0%</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="65" x="10" height="50" width="30"><span class="lineChartLabel ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">0.5%</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="15" x="10" height="50" width="30"><span class="lineChartLabel ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">1%</span></foreignObject><foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="-15" x="10" height="30" width="30"><span class="lineChartLabel ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 30px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">1.5%</span></foreignObject></g></svg>
```

I tried everything I could find, like [simg.js](https://github.com/krunkosaurus/simg)  or this script, for example:

```
var svg  = document.getElementById('test-chart'),
xml  = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg),
data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(xml),
img  = new Image();
img.setAttribute('src', data)
document.body.appendChild(img)
```

But the generated image is always "broken", i.e. doesn't appear at all. The same script with a simpler SVG string works just fine.

I don't understand exactly what's wrong with my string, which is generated by chartist.js and displays nicely in the browser, but it seems the culprit are the `<foreignObject>` elements, as if I remove them, things work fine.

Is there a way to convert that SVG string into an image with JS?

Comment: Maybe the relativ width and height is the problem. Do you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser

Comment: What about using canvas instead of xml. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230293/how-to-convert-svg-to-png-using-html5-canvas-javascript-jquery-and-save-on-serve)

Comment: @Ghita before drawing to a canvas, you have to pass your svg into an `<img>` tag. Have a look at the post you linked to ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `xmlns` attribute set on the `<span>` elements contained in the `<foreignObjects>` are wrong. 
Currently they are set to `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` which is the default XML namespace. It should be `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` since the element you are including belong to the xhtml namespace.

I do believe that you didn't set that yourself and that the library you do use did this.

You could leave its authors an issue report, but note that IE<11 didn't support this `<foreignObject>` tag, and that current Safari have some security restrictions on `<img>`tag representing such a tag (if you want to draw it back to a canvas, it will taint this one). So in *my personal opinion* the use of this tag is still not recommended.

Also note that, as others said, you have to set absolute `width` and `height` attribute to the root `<svg>` so it displays correctly in `<img>` tag.

Finally, you don't need to base64 encode your string, and the `'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, '` dataURI header is the only one supported by all browsers from IE9 to Edge.

Here is how your markup should look like :

```js
var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(test)
var dataURI = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);
var img = new Image();
img.src = dataURI;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

```html
<h3>
svg version
</h3>

<svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="500" height="200" class="ct-chart-line" id="test" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <g class="ct-grids">
    <line y1="165" y2="165" x1="50" x2="406.984375" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line>
    <line y1="115" y2="115" x1="50" x2="406.984375" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line>
    <line y1="65" y2="65" x1="50" x2="406.984375" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line>
    <line y1="15" y2="15" x1="50" x2="406.984375" class="ct-grid ct-vertical"></line>
  </g>
  <g>
    <g series-name="performance" class="ct-series ct-series-a">
      <path d="M50,165C53.57,165,403.415,155,406.984,155" class="ct-line"></path>
    </g>
    <g series-name="bemchmark" class="ct-series ct-series-b">
      <path d="M50,165C53.57,165,403.415,45,406.984,45" class="ct-line"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g class="ct-labels">
    <foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="40" y="170" width="356.984375" height="20" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span class="lineChartLabel ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 357px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Jan</span></foreignObject>
    <foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" x="396.984375"
    y="170" width="30" height="20"><span class="lineChartLabel ct-horizontal ct-end" style="width: 30px; height: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Feb</span></foreignObject>
    <foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="115" x="10" height="50" width="30" ><span class="lineChartLabel ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">0%</span></foreignObject>
    <foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="65" x="10" height="50" width="30" ><span class="lineChartLabel ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">0.5%</span></foreignObject>
    <foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="15" x="10" height="50" width="30" ><span class="lineChartLabel ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 50px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">1%</span></foreignObject>
    <foreignObject style="overflow: visible;" y="-15" x="10" height="30" width="30" ><span class="lineChartLabel ct-vertical ct-start" style="height: 30px; width: 30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">1.5%</span></foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
<h3>
img version
</h3>
```

So if you can't fix the issue before, you'll have to loop through all your HTML elements contained into the `<foreignObject>` elements and fix that manually (`HTMLelem.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')`)

Comment: I've been trying to adapt the above to generate a PNG image. Again, I tried everything I could find but nothing works with this corrected SVG string and PhantomJS! Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

you can use fabric js:
http://fabricjs.com/

```
var addShape = function(shapeName) {

fabric.loadSVGFromURL('../assets/' + shapeName + '.svg', function(objects, options) {
  var loadedObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   loadedObject.set({
     left: 0,
     top:0,
     angle:0
   }).setCoords();
  canvas.add(loadedObject);
  window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
  });
};
```