# svg to png with external source stylesheet (google fonts)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, fonts, png

I'm trying to export svg to png, and auto-download the png. 
I was able to generate the svg to png with google fonts (copied it to 'canvas' using JS), and the 'copied version' was ok, but when I download the file, the font goes back to default font.

I tried many ideas I have found on the web, but nothing helped. 
 Does anyone have an idea?

 I'm working with .net, if it matters somehow.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<button>Download SVG</button>
<div></div>
<canvas style="visibility: hidden;"  id="canvas"></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas = d3.select("div").append("svg")
        .attr("font-size", "50px")
        .attr("width", 150)
        .attr("height", 150)
        .attr("font-family", "Exo 2")
   var circle = canvas.append("circle")
       .attr("cx", 50)
       .attr("cy", 50)
       .attr("r", 50)
       .text("lalala");
   var text = canvas.append("text")
       .attr("x", 100)
       .attr("y", 100)
       .attr("fill", "green")
       .attr("style", "font-family:'Exo 2';")
       .attr("font-size", "20px")
       .text("lalala");


    var btn = document.querySelector('button');
    var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    var text = document.querySelector('text');
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');


    function triggerDownload(imgURI) {
        var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
            view: window,
            bubbles: false,
            cancelable: true
        });
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('download', 'svgImage.png');
        a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
        a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        a.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
        var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
        var img = new Image();
        var svgBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            var imgURI = canvas
                .toDataURL('image/png')
                .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

            triggerDownload(imgURI);
        };

        img.src = url;
    });
</script>
```

enter code here

Comment: There are lots of questions on this subject e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402584/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-canvas-when-drawing-dom-objects-in-svg/42405731#42405731 why are none of them suitable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Google fonts in Canvas when Drawing DOM objects in SVG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402584/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-canvas-when-drawing-dom-objects-in-svg)