# Write svg latex into a canvas html

Tags: html, canvas, latex, mathjax

My goal is to record maths scripts running on the canvas and at the same time record sound from the mic (I am a math teacher). I would like very much to allow latex formulas. Of course latex formulas do not write directly to canvas. MathJax can produce SVG elements. I wonder if it is possible to go from SVG->image->canvas, using javascript. I don't care if the obtained image on canvas is a little blured.
I couldn't find good examples of this yet on the internet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is no Latex to canvas direct way.

You can however draw an SVG over a canvas. See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230293/how-to-draw-an-inline-svg-in-dom-to-a-canvas/33227005) to see how to proceed from an SVG in the DOM (which MathJax should give you).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed that's possible. The trick here is to grab the SVG output of MathJax and draw it to a temporary `<img>` element, which in-turn is drawn to an on-screen canvas afterwards.

The actual `<svg>` element is a children of the `<mjx-container>` element returned by a call to MathJax's `tex2svg()` method.

Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let equation = "x = \\sin \\left( \\frac{\\pi}{2} \\right)";
let svg = MathJax.tex2svg(equation).firstElementChild;

let img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = (e) => {
  let tempWidth = e.target.naturalWidth;
  let tempHeight = e.target.naturalHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(e.target, canvas.width / 2 - tempWidth / 2, canvas.height / 2 - tempHeight / 2, tempWidth, tempHeight)
}
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>\n' + svg.outerHTML);
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, that would help a lot!!